# Alexa skill ki manual input

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new in Alexa skill kit development 
 
I have already read Tutorials on Alexa Skill Kit 
I have to implement Alexa Skill , In which I need to manually send command and want Alexa to speak it.

i.e When user login in system I can fire API as Alexa request and I want Alexa device to Speak that for example "Welcome Have a great day"

Is it Possible ? Or Any other alternatives. ?

Comment: Alexa test console I have tried to send JSON to Alexa . It is retiring JSON instead of text

Answer (score 1):

Notifications for Alexa skill are in still in beta. You can apply for the access to it by filling up this form here : https://alexa.au1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_72lplGGegxNZ9Ln

Answer (score 0):

If **Push Notifications** is what you're looking for, then the answer is ***YES***.

Since in the comments you said, *"You are not asking for HOW TO DO IT"*, so I'll just let this link here for your reference. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html

Comment: Thanks For your answer , Link is AVS (Voice services) and what I need is skill kit. As I told you I have just started so I don't have idea that how can we Link both AVS and skill kit.

Comment: As I am iOS dev. and I have created Demo for AVS in iOS where I am able to login with Amazon login kit and able to communicate through device mike . So Is it possible to do it with amazon echo devices ? ,  I want to upvote but It required min. 15 rep sorry for that

Comment: Did you check this post : https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/833b9af4-26e6-47d2-a13d-bdbd9a257512/expanded-developer-preview-of-notifications-for-alexa-skills

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use proactive events for your skill. They are now commercially available. You will be able to send a notification to your skill and the Amazon device will blink (yellow). However you will still need to say "Alexa check my notifications" to retrieve the actual message

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html

Another idea would be to use "progressive response" feature: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html

You can fire the interaction to alexa when your API is invoked and send a progressive response. Not really a notification but it might serve you. This way you will not need to ask to check the notifications to Alexa but directly get the voice message in the progressive responses